# Create a FormControl Dynamically with Reactive Forms in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have angular response like this

```
    dropdown1: {enabled: true, label: "Country", eformVisible: false}
dropdown2: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown2 Label", eformVisible: false, }
dropdown3: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown3 Label", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 32}
dropdown4: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown4 Label", eformVisible: false, }
dropdown5: {enabled: false, label: "Dropdown5 Label", eformVisible: false, }
text1: {enabled: true, label: "Text1 Custom field", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "ADMIN_API", order: 0, …}
text2: {enabled: false, label: "Text2 Label ", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 1, …}
text3: {enabled: false, label: "Text3 Label ", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 2, …}
text4: {enabled: false, label: "Text4 Label ", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 3, …}
text5: {enabled: false, label: "Text5 Label ", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 4, …}
text6: {enabled: false, label: "Text6 Label ", eformVisible: false, mandatory: "NOT_MANDATORY", order: 5, …}
```

above response should bind to the angular reactive form need to bind the data which value enabled and save data .I have written sample code but response data is different in my case . please help me how to handle this kind of data.

[Sample code please click here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/praveen-dynamic-forms?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: Have you an interfaces for your response?

Comment: no I don't have @RomanA.